# specify # of task writers for AWS Athena `insert into ...` query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

We are using `insert into $table select ...` in AWS Athena to write data to S3. It ended up with 30 small s3 files. We want to write the results into one large S3 file. On presto, we can set `task.writer-count` to limit # of writers. Is there anyway that we can do this on Athena?

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/admin/properties.html#task-writer-count

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bucketed_by` and `bucket_count`. Here's an example from [Examples of CTAS Queries - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE ctas_avro_bucketed 
WITH (
      format = 'AVRO', 
      external_location = 's3://my_athena_results/ctas_avro_bucketed/', 
      partitioned_by = ARRAY['nationkey'], 
      bucketed_by = ARRAY['mktsegment'], 
      bucket_count = 3) 
AS SELECT key1, name1, address1, phone1, acctbal, mktsegment, comment1, nationkey 
FROM table1;
```